# Android Studio dos botones reproducen mismo archivo

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola como andan? estoy tratando de hacer una botonera de sonidos en Android Studio y puse dos botones "btn1" y "personajitos" (les dejo el codigo mas abajo) a la hora de probar la aplicación cualquiera de los dos botones me reproduce el mismo archivo, Android Studio no me marca ningun error en el codigo asi que no se cual puede ser el problema, desde ya gracias por sus respuestas.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    Button btn1;
    Button personajitos;

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        personajitos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.personajitos);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.peroperopero);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.unospersonajitos);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        personajitos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Haría falta ver donde le indicas que audio va a reproducir cada MediaPlayer, suponog que estará en el xml. ¿Puedes ponerlo? Te recomiendo que leas también [tour] y [ask] para que conozcas mejor el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La cuestión es que creas primero un `MediaPlayer` con un audio y seguido lo creas con otro. 
Te recomiendo que crees el audio en el momento en que pinchas cada botón, así conseguiras ejecutar los dos audios.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    Button btn1;
    Button personajitos;

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        personajitos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.personajitos);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity, R.raw.peroperopero);
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        personajitos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity, R.raw.unospersonajitos);
                mp.start();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

He metido los audios uno en cada aunque igual tu quieres que suenen en distinto botón. Solo tendrías que cambair el raw que quiere ejecutar.

Comment: Hola Iñigo gracias por la respuesta! hago lo que decis y me sale este error "android studio cannot resolve method" y se pone en rojo todo esto "this, R.raw.peroperopero" también pasa lo mismo con "this, R.raw.unospersonajitos"

Comment: Tienes razçon, el this hace referencia al onClickListener ahí adentro y hay que cambiarlo por el MainActivity o MainActivity.this..

Comment: Muchisimas gracias sos un genio!!! funciono!!! =D